# Is it possible to counter StackOverflowError with Memory clear?

Tags: memory, stack-overflow

We all know StackOverflowError occurs commonly from bad recursive functions causing the heaps of memory to collide. But what if each time you run the function you clear up the memory (set value to null)? Will it allow infinite loop with no error?

Comment: I did not know that the heaps of memory collide. TIL

Comment: according to the answer to Stackoverflow error, the "heap" can collide with the "Stack": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stackoverflowerror

Answer (score 0):

> We all know StackOverflowError occurs commonly from bad recursive functions causing the heaps of memory to collide.

This is incorrect. Assuming you're talking about Java here, StackOverflowError is thrown when your thread's stack exceeds the configured limit, which is typically at least 256 kB, and no more than a couple of megabytes. It doesn't have to actually collide with the heap -- this concept doesn't really apply in a multithreaded environment.